# PHP - How Do I Create Multiple Form Fields Based On Selection Using Php with validation

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am create the simple with the validation. I have the field like firstname,Mobileno,city,email and add more option(selection).

I need to put validation and if mobile no already exist throw the error message. how can i put the validation.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Show Multiple Form Using Drop down Option - Demo Preview</title>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<!-- importing font family from google fonts -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="multipleform.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/multipleform.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
<div class ="container">
<h2>Dynamically Created Form Fields Based On Selection</h2>
<div id="selected_form_code">
 <select id="select_btn">
 <option value="0">--Select No Of Form to Display for Registration--</option>
 <option value="1">One</option>
 <option value="2">Two</option>
 <option value="3">Three</option>
 <option value="4">Four</option>
 <option value="5">Five</option>
 </select>
 </div>
    <div id="form1">    
        <form id="form_submit" action="#" method="post">
         <!-- dynamic Registration Form Fields Creates here-->
        </form>
    </div> 
<!------ right side advertisement div ----------------->

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My Js file is here

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $('select#select_btn').change(function(){

    var sel_value = $('option:selected').val();
    if(sel_value==0)
    {
        //Resetting Form 
        $("#form_submit").empty();
        $("#form1").css({'display':'none'});
    }
    else{
        //Resetting Form 
        $("#form_submit").empty();

        //Below Function Creates Input Fields Dynamically 
        create(sel_value);

        //appending submit button to form
        $("#form_submit").append(
        $("<input/>",{type:'submit', value:'Register'})
        )
        }   
    }); 

function create(sel_value){
   for(var i=1;i<=sel_value;i++)   
       {
       $("div#form1").slideDown('slow');

        $("div#form1").append(
        $("#form_submit").append(
        $("<div/>",{id:'head'}).append(
        $("<h3/>").text("Registration Form"+i)),
        $("<input/>", {type:'text', placeholder:'Name'+i, name:'name_'+i}),
        $("<br/>"),
        $("<input/>", {type:'text', placeholder:'Email'+i, name:'email_'+i}),
        $("<br/>"),
        $("<textarea/>", {placeholder:'Mobile'+i, type:'text', name:'Mobile'+i}),
        $("<br/>"),     
        $("<hr/>"),
        $("<br/>")
                     ))
        }

    }


});
```

How to put validation for the mobile no and email id. Check the mobile no duplication.

Answer (score 0):

If you can create multiple fields on form . you can write use j query and append any filed with proper format also you can use ajax and submit form without loading and result get on same page.

Comment: Hi Amit, can you give some example or idea how to implement